# Finding 1919 birth record from Veracruz, Mexico?

Tags: birth-records, 1910s, mexico

I am looking for information regarding my grandmother who was born in a place call Ixhuacán de los Reyes, Veracruz, Mexico back in 1919.

Her mother and twin brother died apparently at birth and she was left with her father who died somewhere before her 5th birthday.

Her parents were Isidro Cordova Licher and Felipa Flores Pena.

How could I find a birth record for my grandmother and/or her twin?

Comment: As you will see in the [help/on-topic] our privacy policy says that we need to take care about how we ask whenever we are researching anyone born less than 100 years ago, like your grandmother.  I have deleted her name from your question but if you can provide evidence that she is deceased then that can be put back in.

Comment: I have her death certificate how can I provided to you? if I may ask

Comment: I'm reluctant to suggest posting the certificate itself so can you perhaps just include the certificate jurisdiction and number for now.

Answer (score 2):

Both Church and Civil records are available for this region on Familysearch but **not** fully name indexed so must be searched by going to the list of all records for Veracruz and then finding the image set and then the correct parish or town.

For example baptisms appear to start [here](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:33SQ-GPC9-V72?i=72&wc=3P7D-SPD%3A176848901%2C176848902%2C177078201%3Fcc%3D1883382&cc=1883382) for 1919 in the church records, I had a brief scan but didn't see them. If you can find her birthdate from later records that would aid in your search.

Comment: I checked those record but it seems they are incomplete. She born 08/23/1919 on Izhuacan de los Reyes Veracruz, Mexico. But since she was an orphan we do not have too many details, only names.

Comment: After her father died, was she sent to live with other relatives? You might have more luck tracking the side lines.

Comment: She was sent out of town to live with somebody but I am not sure they were blood related and this people are already gone too ...